# Performance comparison of dynamic neural networks

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I performed a time series analysis on `Recurrent neural networks (RNNs)`, `Feedforward network (FFNN)` `Elman neural networks (ELNN)` and `nonlinear autoregressive network with exogenous inputs (NARX)`.During analysis I observed the following points:

- `RNN` performed better than `NARX`, `ELNN`, `FFNN`  networks on same dataset and optimal parameters as shown in below table. In literature, it has been mentioned that the structure of all these neural networks are quite same. If the structure is quite the same, why results are different for every model?
- Do the results in the table are making sense?. Did I make any mistake?
  [image]